# Input Elements inside grid container

Tags: html, css

Placing input elements inside a grid container overruns the width of the container.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

```css
.grid-container{
        display: grid;    
        width: 700px;
        grid-gap: 0.5em 0.8em;        
        grid-template-columns: 10% 30% 20% 20% 20%;            
    }
    .grid-container input{
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item"><input type="text"></input></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><input type="text"></input></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><input type="text"></input></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><input type="text"></input></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><input type="text"></input></div>          
      </div>
```

Comment: your total columns width is 95% instead of 100%

Comment: I changed the 25% to 30% but the elements still over-run the width of the container.

Comment: box-sizing:border-box to input

Comment: you need to account for `grid-gap` and add `box-sizing: border-box` to inputs. [demo](https://jsbin.com/mivurugola/1/edit?css,output)

Comment: Yousaf:  Your demo does not work.  The inputs still extend past the width of the grid container.

Comment: i have checked the demo, inputs are within the bounds of the container. Click the demo link again.

Comment: Yes, I did.  It does appear to work.  But why will it work with fr units and not % units??

Comment: `fr` units will account for the `grid-gap` whereas when you define units in `%`, you will have to make sure that `grid-gap` plus column widths should not be more than the available width in the container. In your case, since you have defined 100% width (10 + 30 + 20 + 20 + 20), inputs will overflow the bounds of the container because of `grid-gap`.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you post as an answer so I can credit you.